# Apache Spark:Which one is more efficient?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Code is writed by scala,I'm wonder which one is more efficient:

```
    src.filter(word=>!word.contain("xx").map{word=>(word,1))
```

or :

```
    //src:Array("xx","c","d")
    //if word contains xx,fuc will return (),how to deal with it ?
    src.map(word=>if(!word.contain("xx")(word,1))
    //result:Array((), (c,1), (d,1))
```

If word contains xx,fuc will return (),how to deal with it ?

Comment: Why don't you try profiling it yourself to find out?

Comment: if word contains xx,fuc will return (),how to deal with it ?

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense, your missing some braces somewhere.  If your too lazy to profile something yourself like @Jules suggested, then at least please write valid code, put spaces around binary operators and after commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
src.map(word => if(!word.contains("xx")) (word,1))
```

This results in `Array[Any]` instead of `Array[(String, Int)]` because if the word contains "xx" it maps to `()` (Unit).

The proper way would be to use either `flatMap` or `collect` method.

```
src.flatMap { case word if ! word.contains("xx") => Some((word, 1)) 
              case _ => None }       

src.collect { case word if ! word.contains("xx") => (word, 1) } // preferred
```